# Is Newton's third law due to inertia?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, momentum, conservation-laws, inertia

Newton's third law states that each force has an equal and opposite force. If I kicked a ball, it would apply the same force on me. Is this due to the ball's inertia? To clarify, is the ball exerting a force on me because it wants to stay in its original position?

Comment: related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/66057/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Newton's third law is a consequence of conservation of momentum, which we have never been able to falsify. Consider a system of two particles with total momentum $\vec P$ such that

$$ \vec P = \vec p_1 + \vec p_2. $$

Noting the relationship between force and impulse, $\vec F = \frac{d\vec p}{dt}$, we can take a time derivative to find

$$ \frac{d\vec P}{dt} = \frac{d\vec p_1}{dt} + \frac{d\vec p_2}{dt} = \vec F_{\rm 2\, on\, 1} + \vec F_{\rm 1\, on\, 2}. $$

If the total momentum is conserved, then $\frac{d \vec P}{dt} = 0$, and we have
$$ \vec F_{\rm 2\, on\, 1} = - \vec F_{\rm 1\, on\, 2}.$$

The ball exerts a force back on you in order to conserve linear momentum.

Comment: What about a static case?

Comment: V.F.  The total momentum is still constant.

Comment: I don't disagree with that, but in your derivation, you rely on the relationship F=dp/dt for each particle, which does not seem to be valid in the static case.