# Need of Newton's first law

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

The second Newton's law of motion is : $\vec{a} = \frac{\vec{F}net}{m}$

I wanted to ask what was the need to define first law when we can easily derive from second law that when $\vec{F}net=0$ then ${\vec{a}=0}$.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can one of Newton's Laws of motion be derived from other Newton's Laws of motion?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/66057/)

Answer (score 2):

I found on French Wikipedia something that answers your question

> For a body subjected to a resultant of zero forces, we find Newton's
> first law, that is to say a uniform rectilinear motion. At first
> analysis, one may wonder what is the usefulness of the first law since
> it seems to be a consequence of the second. In reality, in Newton's
> statement, this is not the case because the first law is not presented
> as a particular case of the second but as a sufficient condition for
> the application of the latter.
>
> Indeed, to state the first law is first of all to affirm the existence
> of the Galilean references. This constitutes an extremely strong
> postulate which allows, in modern presentations of classical
> mechanics, to define the Galilean frames which are the only
> frames in which the second law is valid. In the absence of
> the first law, the second law is inapplicable since we cannot define
> its domain of validity. Consequently, the logical order in which the
> laws are stated is not the result of chance but that of a coherent
> intellectual construction.
>
> Then, this first law states the principle of isolation of the solid:
> we consider the external forces which act on it, and we do not take
> into account what happens internally.